# Selenium XPath: How to find text within a span class tag?

Tags: html, class, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have several objects that look exactly the same, except for the text within 'span class'. In the example below, I need to locate the phone number, '+15551234567':

```
<span class="contact-number">+15551234567 </span>
```

I have tried several css selectors and xpath queries and have not had much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show other similar elements or better part of html with parent items, so we'll try to identify required item correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css seletor for this:

```
span.contact-number
```

xpath:

```
//span[@class='contact-number']
```

or

```
//span[text()='+15551234567 ']
```

and you can get text from locator in that way:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("locatorHere")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks! here is what I ended up using:  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='+15551234567 ']")).click();